# How to create a background thread in iOS which continues after the app has been hidden from view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, multithreading, mqtt

I am new to iPhone development and working through **SamsTechYourself** iPhone Development. I am trying to write an app that receives push notifications from an `MQTT` broker (similar to Facebook Messenger).

I have compiled a C library called `libmosquitto` and have it running on the emulator, however I  am stuck trying to figure out how to make it continue to listen for notifications, while the app is in the background. My book mentions modes for `VOIP` and background sounds but does not go into much detail.

Could anyone point me to a good tutorial in iPhone and background processes or gives me some tips on how to get started?

What I want is a twitter like app, which gives a little popup info when a new message has been pushed from the broker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do exactly what you are trying to do (run a background process, listen for notifications). All background notifications on iOS are handled through Apple Push Notification Services (APNS). In short, you need to setup a server to send messages through APNS and APNS will notify the user that something has happened. The user can then choose to open your app.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ApplePushService/ApplePushService.html

Comment: Thanks, I will look into this, it looks like it will do the job. My understanding though, was the Facebook Messenger used MQTT for this, perhaps they just use MQTT while in the foreground.